# Minimum length of confidence interval for $\theta$ when $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim\operatorname{Beta}( \theta,1)$

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval

I am asked to find the minimum length confidence interval for a Beta distribution with parameters $a=\theta$ and $b=1$ and probability $1-\alpha$.

I have found that $-2\theta \sum_i \log(X_i)$ has distribution $\chi^2_{2n}$ and is therefore a pivotal quantity. However, I don't know how to find the minimum length confidence interval: I know I have to find two points $a, b$ such that $F(b) - F(a) = 1-\alpha$ and $f(b) = f(a)$ but I don't know how to tackle the problem numerically. Am I right on my approach until now? How should I approach the problem of solving for $b$ and $a$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I know I have to" is predicated on an assumption that is not necessarily true: namely, that $f$ is everywhere continuous.  Draw a picture of the graph of $f$ to see what's going on.  It's also unclear why your statistic ought to have a chi-squared distribution with $2n$ degrees of freedom, because it sure looks like the degrees of freedom must depend on $a.$

Comment: @whuber I don't know if I understand you. In first place, $-\log(X_i)$ is an exponential with parameter $\theta$, so $-2 \theta \log(X)$ is an exponential of parameter $\frac{1}{2}$ and the sum of all them has distribution $\chi_{2n}$. If I understand well, the pivotal statistic distribution can't depend on $a$ or we couldn't use it to calculate confidence intervals.

In second place, $f = \frac{1}{2^n \Gamma(n)} x^{n-1} e^\frac{-x}{2}$. How isn't this function everywhere continous in $(0,1)$?

Comment: That is true--I forgot that $a$ is a scale parameter for $\log(X)$ rather than a shape parameter.  But the advice is sound: especially for $n=1,$ graph the density of your pivotal statistic and look at it.

Comment: @whuber I see what do you mean. How can I approach the construction of a minimum length confidence interval then?

Comment: Cross-posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3668113/321264

Comment: @StubbornAtom Could you limit your comments to those that may shed light on the question? I already told you I would delete one of the post as soon as one of them gets an answer.

Comment: The comment is not for you. And you are not doing me any favour.

Comment: @StubbornAtom I am not doing it as a favour, just ouf of respect for the rules. I just don’t see the point of commenting if the comment is not going to add anything to the question.